# Comparing only Year and Month

Tags: sql, db2

I'm using this to compare Year and month, but it failing when month is less than current month even though the year is greater than current year

```
SELECT * FROM DUMMY_TABLE WHERE
YEAR(PREV_ELIG_REV_DT) >= YEAR(CURRENT TIMESTAMP)
AND MONTH(PREV_ELIG_REV_DT) >= MONTH(CURRENT TIMESTAMP)
```

Comment: Perhaps you could illustrate the values that don't work as expected int a http://sqlfiddle.com/?

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: I'm using DB2 @JosephB

Comment: So, you want everything after the first of the current month?  Is there some reason you can't just compare to the start of the current month?  Pretty much any time you use a function on a column, the optimizer has to ignore indices while running the query (will make it slower).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could add and extra condition to match the situation when the YEAR is equal..

```
SELECT * 
  FROM DUMMY_TABLE 
  WHERE
     YEAR(PREV_ELIG_REV_DT) > YEAR(CURRENT TIMESTAMP)
  OR (    YEAR(PREV_ELIG_REV_DT) = YEAR(CURRENT TIMESTAMP)
     AND MONTH(PREV_ELIG_REV_DT) >= MONTH(CURRENT TIMESTAMP))
```

**UPDATE**

As @Clockwork-Muse said, an alternative approach that *may* yield better performance would be to get the beginning of the current month and compare against that:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM DUMMY_TABLE 
  WHERE
     PREV_ELIG_REV_DT >= (CURRENT DATE - (DAY(CURRENT DATE)-1) DAYS)
```

Comment: Except, this will ignore indices.  It'd be faster to get the start of the current month and compare to that.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse - you're right. I've updated the answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT * FROM DUMMY_TABLE 
WHERE
     YEAR(PREV_ELIG_REV_DT)*100 + MONTH(PREV_ELIG_REV_DT) 
  >= YEAR(CURRENT TIMESTAMP) * 100 + MONTH(CURRENT TIMESTAMP)
```