# Given starting Year and Month as separate columns, how to tell if a specific year and month are within next 6 months?

Tags: sql

I have a table `A` with two columns named Year and Month. I need to join it with another table `B` also with Year and Month columns. The condition I need to impose is that the month in `B` is within next 6 months of the month in `A`. For example, if `A.Year=2014` and `A.Month=09`, then `B.Year=2015` and `B.Month=01` would be selected because it is within the next 6 months.

I've searched on SO but have not been able to find a solution. [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22414360/comparing-only-year-and-month)
gave me a hint of using `Year*100+Month` calculations. But I am not sure how to add 6 months to such a calculation easily (guess I could use modulo). Does anyone have a good clean solution to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `Year*100+Month` simply use `Year*12+Month`.

```
WHERE B.Year*12+B.Month BETWEEN A.Year*12+A.Month AND A.Year*12+A.Month +6
```

Comment: Bingo! Why didn't I think of that? Thanks.